# Webforms Navbar search/submit button -> event

Tags: c#, .net

I can't seem to get how to use the navbar search/submit event as Im new to this.

Basically I just want to redirect to another page when clicking the Submit button and then use the text in navbar form textbox to match in my product list.

The problem Im having is I dont know where to GET or access the text and clickevent and how to then use them from the masterpage.

Here is an image of my navbar with textbox and submit button:   [navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIGRZ.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

margin: 5%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>

            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

     <%--
```

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">PharmaGistix</a>
            </div>


             <%--SEARCH BUTTON NAVBAR --%>
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="formgroup">
                         <input class="form-control" id="navinput" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" id="navsearchbtn" runat="server" OnClick="navSearch" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>       
                </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/ItemManager">Manage Items</a></li>
                   <%-- <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>--%>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Search">Search</a></li> 
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/OrderHistory">Order History</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/CheckoutBasket">Checkout Basket</a></li>                       
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you're using bootstrap. That just gives you the divs to wrap around your normal buttons. If you're using webforms you will have a button event like normal. If you're using MVC you will have a normal HTML button or a razor syntax button.

Comment: Im using webforms,  I know this may seem like a stupid question but where can i then get these events cuz i have been looking for them for like an hour now.  Tx

Comment: Are you using the Design or Source editor? In design just double click the button. In source find your button and Add OnClick="" and select generate method.

Comment: Hi tx, I see your getting my problem.  Neither double clicking on design or adding onclick event in source generates the event. ( Im doing this in the masterpage)

Comment: Post the code from each part of the master page... the aspx page and the code behind. It will make this go much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Does the user get redirected to the search page or do the results come back via ajax? If the first one, I would just use a basic HTML form to send the information, for the latter, you could use some simple jQuery to bring the results back.
jQuery example w/ post or get, whatever you need. Using get here since you mentioned it -

```
$.get("/url-with-products.aspx?query=" + $("#id-of-search-input").val(),  
function(data) {
});
```

And then on the .net page you could just Request.Params["query"] and store it in a string to use for querying a database.

Comment: thanks, in HTML in the MasterPage?  do I then put in a href at the button and then save what is in the textbox with onclick event somehow?

Comment: Try adding this before your input - 
<form method="get" action="YOUR-URL-HERE">

And this after the button - 
</form>

And then on the search results page you can get the parameters based on the name/id of the input.

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio adds those for no reason. You can get rid of the ones that were in the file when you started. That's what I always do.

Comment: No, those are basically just boxes to put stuff in. If you could edit your original post and add the code we could see if there's an issue or if anything is missing.